# How to map array of object returning from api in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, model

I have following REST api endpoint I need to consume from Flutter application. I have fromJson, toJson model mapping as usual.  How can I map these in to array.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 0,
    "type": "Create",
    "tableName": "Province",
    "dateTime": "2022-03-14T03:23:41.338932",
    "oldValues": null,
    "newValues": "{\"NameEN\":\"Banteay Meanchey\",\"NameKH\":\"\\u1794\\u1793\\u17D2\\u1791\\u17B6\\u1799\\u1798\\u17B6\\u1793\\u1787\\u17D0\\u1799\",\"Type\":\"\\u1781\\u17C1\\u178F\\u17D2\\u178F\"}",
    "affectedColumns": null,
    "primaryKey": "{\"Code\":1}"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 0,
    "type": "Create",
    "tableName": "Province",
    "dateTime": "2022-03-14T03:23:41.351456",
    "oldValues": null,
    "newValues": "{\"NameEN\":\"Battambang\",\"NameKH\":\"\\u1794\\u17B6\\u178F\\u17CB\\u178A\\u17C6\\u1794\\u1784\",\"Type\":\"\\u1781\\u17C1\\u178F\\u17D2\\u178F\"}",
    "affectedColumns": null,
    "primaryKey": "{\"Code\":2}"
  }
]
```

I try to have following code but it doesnot work. One way is to return {} json object instead of [] array of object. But I do not want to change how API return the json.

```
Future<List<Audit>> getAudits() async {
    final jsonString = await dio.get('auditlogs');
    final List decodedJson = json.decode(jsonString.data.toString());
    final List<Audit> audits = decodedJson.map((e) => Audit.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return audits;
  }
```

**Update additional context**
I print the jsonString after

```
final jsonString = await dio.get('auditlogs');
```

Here below is the result. what wrong with this json.

```
[{id: 1, userId: 0, type: Create, tableName: Province, dateTime:
2022-03-14T03:23:41.338932, oldValues: null, newValues:
{"NameEN":"Banteay
Meanchey","NameKH":"\u1794\u1793\u17D2\u1791\u17B6\u1799\u1798\u17B6\u1
793\u1787\u17D0\u1799","Type":"\u1781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"},
affectedColumns: null, primaryKey: {"Code":1}}, {id: 2, userId: 0,
type: Create, tableName: Province, dateTime:
2022-03-14T03:23:41.351456, oldValues: null, newValues:
{"NameEN":"Battambang","NameKH":"\u1794\u17B6\u178F\u17CB\u178A\u17C6\u
1794\u1784","Type":"\u1781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"}, affectedColumns:
null, primaryKey: {"Code":2}}, {id: 3, userId: 0, type: Create,
tableName: Province, dateTime: 2022-03-14T03:23:41.351487, oldValues:
null, newValues: {"NameEN":"Kampong
Cham","NameKH":"\u1780\u17C6\u1796\u1784\u17CB\u1785\u17B6\u1798","Type
":"\u1781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"}, affectedColumns: null, primaryKey:
{"Code":3}}, {id: 4, userId: 0, type: Create, tableName: Province,
dateTime: 2022-03-14T03:23:41.351503, oldValues: null, newValues:
{"NameEN":"Kampong
Chhnang","NameKH":"\u1780\u17C6\u1796\u1784\u17CB\u1786\u17D2\u1793\u17
B6\u17C6\u1784","Type":"\u1781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"},
affectedColumns: null, primaryKey: {"Code":4}}, {id: 5, userId: 0,
type: Create, tableName: Province, dateTime:
2022-03-14T03:23:41.351515, oldValues: null, newValues:
{"NameEN":"Kampong
Speu","NameKH":"\u178F\u1780\u17C6\u1796\u1784\u17CB\u179F\u17D2\u1796\
u17BA","Type":"\u1781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"}, affectedColumns: null,
primaryKey: {"Code":5}}, {id: 6, userId: 0, type: Create, tableName:
Province, dateTime: 2022-03-14T03:23:41.351528, oldValues: null,
newValues: {"NameEN":"Kampong
Thom","NameKH":"\u1780\u17C6\u1796\u1784\u17CB\u1792\u17C6","Type":"\u1
781\u17C1\u178F\u17D2\u178F"}, affectedColumns: null, primaryKey:
{"Code":6}}]
```

**Data Model**

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'audit.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Audit {
  int id;
  int userId;
  String? type;
  String? tableName;
  DateTime dateTime;
  String? oldValues;
  String? newValues;
  String? affectedColumns;
  String? primaryKey;

  Audit(
    this.id,
    this.userId,
    this.type,
    this.tableName,
    this.dateTime,
    this.oldValues,
    this.newValues,
    this.affectedColumns,
    this.primaryKey,
  );

  factory Audit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AuditFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AuditToJson(this);
}
```

Generated JSON Serialization

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'audit.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Audit _$AuditFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Audit(
      json['id'] as int,
      json['userId'] as int,
      json['type'] as String?,
      json['tableName'] as String?,
      DateTime.parse(json['dateTime'] as String),
      json['oldValues'] as String?,
      json['newValues'] as String?,
      json['affectedColumns'] as String?,
      json['primaryKey'] as String?,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$AuditToJson(Audit instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'userId': instance.userId,
      'type': instance.type,
      'tableName': instance.tableName,
      'dateTime': instance.dateTime.toIso8601String(),
      'oldValues': instance.oldValues,
      'newValues': instance.newValues,
      'affectedColumns': instance.affectedColumns,
      'primaryKey': instance.primaryKey,
    };
```

Comment: use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ to generate model

Comment: I could auto generate the model file. but you can check the dio class. something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Future<List<Audit>> getAudits() async {
   var response = await dio.get('auditlogs');

   List<Audit> result = [];

  (jsonDecode(response.bodyString)).forEach((element) {
       result.add(Audit.fromJson(element));
     });

  return result; 
}
```

- Update:

Try this:

```
(jsonDecode(response.data.toString())).forEach((element) {
       result.add(Audit.fromJson(element));
     });
```

Or this:

```
(jsonDecode(response.data)).forEach((element) {
       result.add(Audit.fromJson(element));
     });
```

Comment: it's producing this error  Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at
position 2

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try it too.

Comment: hi. i have updated the question. (jsonDecode(response.data.toString())).forEach((element) {
       result.add(Audit.fromJson(element));
     });. i did try this. but still same.

Comment: Do you have 'toJson' & 'fromJson' in your data model for 'Audit'?

Comment: @M.karima I updated my question. yes i have toJson and fromJson

Comment: it seems the json string is invalid. not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is null value in your JSON but you didn't check for null. Modify the generated code to check for null values before decoding.

I've test it and it worked like charm:

```
  factory Audit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Audit(
      json['id'] as int,
      json['userId'] as int,
      json['type'] as String,
      json['tableName'] as String,
      DateTime.parse(json['dateTime'] as String),
      (json['oldValues'] != null) ? json['oldValues'] as String : '',
      json['newValues'] as String,
      (json['affectedColumns'] != null)
          ? json['affectedColumns'] as String
          : '',
      json['primaryKey'] as String,
    );
  }
```

**Yet better solution:**

Modify your Audit class to support null value such as String?

```
class Audit {
  int id;
  int userId;
  String type;
  String tableName;
  DateTime dateTime;
  String? oldValues;
  String newValues;
  String? affectedColumns;
  String primaryKey;

  Audit(
    this.id,
    this.userId,
    this.type,
    this.tableName,
    this.dateTime,
    this.oldValues,
    this.newValues,
    this.affectedColumns,
    this.primaryKey,
  );
}
```

and refactor Audit.fromJson() to reflect the changes in the class:

```
  factory Audit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Audit(
      json['id'] as int,
      json['userId'] as int,
      json['type'] as String,
      json['tableName'] as String,
      DateTime.parse(json['dateTime'] as String),
      json['oldValues'] as String?,
      json['newValues'] as String,
      json['affectedColumns'] as String?,
      json['primaryKey'] as String,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Great. thank you so much. I had String? at server side, but forgot to add on dart file. also I have to add this  options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.plain,
      ) to dio.get. otherwise, json string will be invalid .

Comment: can you also update your dio.get ?

Comment: you don't need to modify dio.get because it's API related not decoding. your problem is parsing issue. try it and if it's worked accept as answer

Comment: I face the issue if I dont set option: Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2. I print the json inside answer. you can check it

Comment: Future<List<Audit>> getAudits() async {
    var response = await dio.get(
      'auditlogs',
      options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.plain,
      ),
    );
    List<Audit> result = [];

    (jsonDecode(response.data.toString())).forEach((element) {
      result.add(Audit.fromJson(element));
    });
    return result;
  }

Comment: In your answer, from where the JSON String is? Is it expected or what you actually get from the API? I've tested the code from the provided JSON string and it worked. If you code provide the API link so I can tested in my machine

Comment: it is strange. do you have discord? my discord id: chhinsras#7089

Comment: @Sras mine is Phoenixxx#4061

Answer (score -3):

have you imported JSON file in pubspec.yaml

Comment: what json file ? it's getting from api server.

Comment: please chck i just updated my question

Comment: Please share example so he/she can get better idea about solution